# Authorisation got lost, when using a function as onEdit-Trigger or as cell-function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I spend a lot of time to create and modify calendar-events based on lines in a spreadsheet. The plan was to modify the values in the table and update the calendar automatically. So I use a onEdit-Trigger, what worked well some time long.

But however the script-file lost the authorization now, when I use the script-functions as onEdit-Trigger or as cell-function. It works well, when I'm start that functions out of the script-editor. No authorization problems at all.

Is there a way to set the authorization manually? Without the authorization-dialog, that not appears?

[image]

In B42 the date of Easter should be calculated (=Osterdatum(A42;0))
In B43 the Easter date is written by that function, but starter in the script-editor.

The mention line 6 has the following context:

```
// Kalender in Google eintragen
var test = true; // bei true nix schreiben

// Kalender öffnen, um Termine einzutragen
var kalenderID  = "1234567890987654321@group.calendar.google.com"; // Regionalkalender
var meinKalender= CalendarApp.getCalendarById(kalenderID);  // Line 6
if (test) {
  Logger.log(meinKalender.getName());
}
```

Can anyone help me to get the authorization back?

Comment: No, it is not allowed for a custom function to influence cells that it does not directly `return` a value to (i.e. cells it is not called from our that are not part of the contiguous array output). Further, custom functions execute anonymously and with no authorization for many services. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#return_values

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that usage as cell-function works, when I don't use setValue() to other cells.

So the question maybe is: 
is it possible to use setValue() to other cells (e.g. C43), when I called the function as cell-function in B42?

Thanks for request.
Udo